# How to check if there is a next page or not from the response of requests without getting Key Error. Python

Tags: python, api, github, pagination, python-requests

So I am calling github API to get the commit messages from some users repositories. And I am creating files to write the messages there...

I want to check if there is another page from my response so that I can call the api again with the page = page + 1

I saw that to check if there is another page you can use:

```
response.links['next']
```

but if there is no 'next' you get an error and your code stops. You don't get a null or something that you can use it in an 'if' statement.

> KeyError: 'next'

**So my questions is: How can I check if there is another page to loop my 'gets' on all pages. And if there is no 'next page' to continute my code...**

*Thank you in advance...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `response.links.get('next', None)`

explanation:
[dict get or default](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm)

Comment: So if there is a next, I get the next but if there is no 'next' I get None? Is that right?

Comment: @AlexRika Yes - you will get None. You dont have to pass None to the get call since it is the default. Use `response.links.get('next')`